# Ethernet-to-I2C box not seen when VPN turned on

Tags: dns, vpn, ethernet

I have an Ethernet-to-I2C interface box (Promira, from Total Phase), connected locally to my laptop via a USB-C to Ethernet adapter. This Promira box works fine with VPN off, but disappears when VPN is turned on. I changed to split tunneling and can make the box appear, temporarily, but the box disappears again after some brief time (it varies, but less than 5 minutes). I *think* I've narrowed it down to something changing in DNS, because if I reset or change DNS settings in the USB-C to Ethernet adapter while VPN is on, the device can temporarily be seen again.

I have the Promira box on a separate sub-net than my internet, which allows the split tunneling.

The Promira box (as I understand from documentation) works with IPv4. I can disable IPv6 on the USB-C Ethernet adapter, and the Promira still works.

Windows 10 laptop.

Internet Ethernet connection:  172.27.35.11

USB-C to Ethernet adapter: 169.254.189.247

Promira box: 169.254.40.66 (the Promira box has a DHCP server built in, so this varies each time the box powers up; I *believe* the Promira box also assigns the IP address of the USB-C adapter)

VPN uses addresses of form 10.x.x.x

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Another observation today - I left VPN on, the first time ~15 minutes, the second time > 30 minutes. I then tried detecting the box again; the first try, failure; but then after that the box was detected multiple times. However, eventually the box becomes hidden again.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with the Promira SW. The Total Phase engineers quickly turned around a fix for this.